# Как вывести значение из TextBox

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Пользователь вводит своё разрешение(например: 1920x1080)
Мне нужно чтобы по нажатии кнопки рядом,выполнялась проверка текста,если всё верно,то текст,введеный пользователем конвентировался в X и Y 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример решения вашей проблемы, я заменил ваш Make IntPoint на обычный Vector2d  но суть от этого не меняется... так же вы можете добавить дополнительные проверки.
Проще всего бы это было сделать через с++ код... но как говорил Вовка -" И так сойдет!"

[image: blueprint ввода расширений]